# PendingIntent is cancelled after cleaning the app from recent app list

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

My alarm clock app uses `AlarmManager` to set alarms and I have a problem with `PendingIntent`s being cancelled when I close the app from recent app list (it happens occasionally on a `KitKat` device and almost constantly on `Marshmallow`), even if the alarm was set a couple minutes ago (so device is not asleep).

Here's how I set an alarm:

```
Calendar alarmCalendar = getCalendarForDay(day);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            (id * 10000 + day.position), getIntent(context, day.position), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long intervalMsec = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intervalMsec, pendingIntent);
} else alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intervalMsec, pendingIntent);
```

getIntent():

```
private Intent getIntent(Context context, int dayPosition) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME + ".alarmId", id);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME + ".dayPosition", dayPosition);
    return intent;
}
```

I've spent quite a while browsing this site and found some explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643850/android-alarm-is-cancelled-after-closing-the-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041208/how-to-reset-alarm-if-app-is-force-closed-in-android) (basically says that it's normal and some manufacturers just do that), but none of them have actually helped me to deal with the problem. Still, I'm pretty sure that canbe solved, since there are some apps that work on all devices (such as `Timely` and other popular alarm clocks).

So does anyone have any thoughts on how those alarms actually deal with `AlarmManager`? Why their intents are never get cancelled?

Comment: Did you register `AlarmReceiver` in your manifest?

Comment: Of course, it usually works, but sometimes it jsut doesn't