# Create Notification each day

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want to create a Notification each Day at 8:00am. I have some data in a SQLite database and every day at this time I want to get the data from it and create a notification from it. The creation of a new notification is no problem but how can I display it every day at this time?

I think I have to work with a Service but how can I tell the system to start this service at the special moment? And what kind of Service should I use? I think if the system calls the service it starts a specific function where I can run my code to connect to the database and create and send my notification to the system right?

What I can't understand is if I register the service in my main Activity why can the system start the service if the user close my app? Can anyone explain that to me? I allways think if my main Activity is destroyed the service is destroyed, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430849/how-to-set-recurring-alarmmanager-to-execute-code-daily

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class and put the notification in a `NotifyService` class. This will set an alarm at 8am everyday:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Current.this , NotifyService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 08);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

Comment: I have same settings still i am getting notification every hour instead of once a day.

Comment: This will work until user reboots his phone. To keep AlarmManager working even after reboot, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512717/android-alarmmanager-after-reboot

Comment: Same here... It is not sending once a day but everytime i open the app

Comment: pre-defined AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY can be used instead of 24*60*60*1000, reduces the chances of error...

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a server. I think the best way to implement this is to use AlarmManager.

[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Comment: typo change AlertManager to AlarmManager