# Sending notifications on a timer everyday on android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm looking for this answer for a few days already on the web. I'm really new to both android java and stackoverflow.

So what I want to do is to send a reminder **everyday at 12:30** to remind my user to use the App (The notification should be send without having the application running, if it's possible).
What I've learned from this website is that I have to create a notifyService class which extends Service.

I've tried every solutions I found, and I've never recieved any notification, so I guess either my NotifyService class is wrong, or I'm calling it in a bad way.

I've tested my creation of the notification (**without using notifyservice**) on the mainActivity and linked it on a button click and it worked fine, so I guess the problem comes from elsewhere.

Here my NotifiyService class :

```
public class NotifyService extends Service{
private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private Handler notificationTimer = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what==0) {
            sendNotifications();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

private Runnable notificationCaller = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Message msg = notificationTimer.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = 0;
        notificationTimer.sendMessage(msg);
    }
};

public void sendNotifications(){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar timer = Calendar.getInstance();
    timer.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    timer.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    timer.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    Long difference = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - timer.getTimeInMillis();

    if(difference<0){
        notificationTimer.postDelayed(notificationCaller, -(difference));
    }
    else{
        notificationTimer.postDelayed(notificationCaller, difference);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    builder.setContentTitle("Pensez à vérifier votre glycémie !");
    builder.setContentText("Bonjour jeune Padawan, il est temps de penser à contrôler ta glycémie.");
    builder.setSubText("Click pour ouvrir Diab'App :)");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    notificationTimer.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    notificationTimer.postDelayed(notificationCaller, 86400000);
}
```

}

And here is my mainActivity : (I won't link all of it because most of it has nothing to deal with the problem here)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* some code for my database init and layouts */

    Intent service = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
    this.startService(service);
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here, is it because I call the startService on the onCreate function, so I have to launch my app to get notify ?

**Thanks !**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487126/create-notification-each-day

Comment: Yes it's the topic i used to implement my NotifyService class, but i couldn't figure out what I did wrong. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to use AlarmManager like in the example. It will then wake up your Service which will only present a notification at onCreate

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler solution for what you're trying to accomplish, the Android [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) class...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your service in androidmanifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".NotifyService"
                 android:enabled="true" />
```