# Setting alarm on daily basis

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I am developing an android app where I am trying to set an alarm on daily basis.And for that I am using Calendar as

```
                alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE,taskdate);
                alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
                alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
                alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
                alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

I was setting the alarm using the below code.

```
     alarmtime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

The Problem with the above code is, the alarm triggers sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

So I am trying it out in one more way. that is, 
Once the alarm triggers, On cancel of that alarm I am trying to set it for the next day using

```
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currenttime, pendingIntent);
```

instead of am.setRepeating(). But now the problem is that, even though there is no looping in the code, the alarm triggers continuously on cancelling it.

Not getting where I am going wrong.
Please Help.Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4431071/1777090

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a `BroadcastReceiver` with the `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission to recreate the alarm every time the phone starts up? Otherwise you'll loose the alarm.

Check it out here http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.nl/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html

Comment: The problem is not on BootUp...The Alarm is not triggering properly sometimes. and On cancel , it is  triggering continuously..