# BOOT_COMPLETED and already executed alarm from AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a repeating alarm from AlarmManager, which is triggered at 7:00 AM every day. As per documentation, there is something called skipped alarm, which executes as soon as it is seen it is behind the schedule.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
```

What i have is a BOOT_COMPLETE receiver, that start my alarmService, main issue is that after say 7:00 AM (as alarm will be executed),  the device is rebooted at 9:00 AM or any time beyond 7:00 AM, the alarm get triggered the second time. Though the alarm manager is doing what it is suppose to do, however, it is not what i expect.

One possible solution is to save last_executed_day into the preferences and check it before triggering that alarm notification.

What are the possible ways over come this pattern ? Though i suggested, way, i don't think, that is standard hack and i'm pretty sure, most of you have faced similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar.CompareTo [Doc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo-java.util.Calendar-) method to check whether time is passed or not then you can initiate the service.You can try something like this :

**Code:**

```
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();

   calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
   calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

   if(calSet.compareTo(current) <= 0){
    //If time passed add for tomo
    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   }

   setAlarm(calSet);
  }};

 private void setAlarm(Calendar cal){


  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustomReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
 }
```

Comment: There is tiny issue over there, alarm will miss a notification. If any time device was switch off for the entire day, and was switched on at say 9:00 PM night. So a better solution, adding your your valuable suggestion is, to save the last executed calendar time to preference and compare it to current. So, if last executed was yesterday NOV 13 7:00 AM and device was switched on at NOV 14 9:00 PM. NOV 14 alarm will not be skipped.

Your logic remains the same, so calSet will be from preferences and when ever alarm fires it saves the current calender.

Answer (score 0):

This links may help you,

http://it-ride.blogspot.in/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html

[How to Set Recurring AlarmManager to execute code daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430849/how-to-set-recurring-alarmmanager-to-execute-code-daily)