# Alarm manager trigger every time app running

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I want to create a repeating alarm from AlarmManager which is triggered at 21:00 every day to show a notification. So i create a service and declare that in manifest, in the service class i wrote a method for schedule repeating alarms.

```
public static void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.cancel(pi);

    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);

}
```

(For test i set the delay INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES).

I call this method at onResume() of my splash screen activity and in a BroadcastReceiver that is set up to receive BOOT_COMPLETED.

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    NotificationService.setRecurringAlarm(this);
}
```

this is my BroadcastReceicer :

```
public class NotificationBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationService.setRecurringAlarm(context);
    }

}
```

and this is my manifest :

```
    <receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".notification.NotificationService" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

the problem is every time i open the app and splashscreen running the alarm triggered and notification will be shown.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? same thing happens to me.

Comment: Compare your system time to the alarm time..if alarm time is less than equal to system time receiver will work..but if not then nothing will happen...Follow this below link for details-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087648/scheduled-notifications-triggers-every-time-i-open-app

Comment: This may be helpful for late comers :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/50437672/7422255

Comment: if you have solved it could you share the answer